# How to connect Eclipse with JPL on OS X

Tags: java, eclipse, prolog, jpl

I've got problem which wasn't solved anywhere else.
I've downloaded `libjpl.dylib` and copied to

> /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.6.4/libexec/lib/swipl-7.6.4/lib/

The output of `otool -L` of the `libjpl.dylib` give me this output:
libjpl.dylib:

> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjsig.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0) /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/server/libjvm.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
>       /usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.6.4/libexec/lib/swipl-7.6.4/lib/x86_64-darwin17.3.0/libswipl.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 7.7.19)
>       /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1252.50.4)

and all paths are correct. The path to `libjpl.dylib` is added to build path of project in `Eclipse` and `-Djava.library.path="/usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.6.4/libexec/lib/swipl-7.6.4/lib/"` is added to VM arguments in `run configuration`. Anyway, when I want to compile it I've got an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>
> jpl.fli.Prolog.thread_self()I
>   at jpl.fli.Prolog.thread_self(Native Method) at jpl.Query.open(Query.java:286) at jpl.Query.hasMoreSolutions(Query.java:256) at jpl.Query.oneSolution(Query.java:688) at jpl.Query.hasSolution(Query.java:759) at Pro.main(Pro.java:12)

What had I miss?

The code:

```
import jpl.*;

public class Pro {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ////it gives the same error even if System.load doesn't exist
    System.load("/usr/local/Cellar/swi-prolog/7.6.4/libexec/lib/swipl-7.6.4/lib/libjpl.dylib");
    Term goal = new Compound( "teacher_of", new Term[]{new Atom("aristotle"),new Atom("alexander")});
    Query q = new Query( goal );
    q.hasSolution();

}

}
```

Comment: JPL needs a runnable SWI-Prolog image. Are you able to correctly start swipl and perform some query on CLI ?

Comment: Yes I can, I made some prolog projects with this swipl and there wasnt a problem to perform any query.